# Django Foreign Key Filter

Tags: django, django-models

I am defining some models for an inventory / work order application I am developing and I've run into a slight sticking point.

Here are some of the models that I'm currently having some difficulty with.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Staff(models.Model):
    ROLE = (
        ('M', 'Mechanic'),
        ('W', 'Warehouse'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    staff_role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE)

class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    item_number = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    date_started = models.DateField()
    date_ended = models.DateField()
    mechanic = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
```

What I would like is for a work order to only be associated with a staff member whose role is set as "Mechanic". Is there a way to restrict this within the model specification based on the models that I have here, or should I deal with this downstream when I set up the views and the forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) parameter to `ForeignKey`:

```
mechanic = models.ForeignKey(Staff, limit_choices_to={'staff_role': 'M'})
```